# problem with print of “Ubercart CCK Checkout Pane” modules

Tags: 7, ubercart, commerce

in ubercart, I'm using Ubercart CCK Checkout Pane module, for adding fields to the Order. Now I have a problem. When I get a print order, cck fields are not in print.

What should I do?